# JavaScript iterating over an array gives wrong value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a a very simple piece of code that doesn't work as I would expect.

```
<script>
var m = {0:[1]}
document.write(JSON.stringify(m[0]) + "<br>");
for(var c in m[0]) document.write(c);
</script>
```

It outputs:

```
[1]
0
```

But I was expecting to get:

```
[1]
1
```

I guess I have some missunderstanding of the way JavaScript works.

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed, so [1] has length 1, item 0 = 1. m[0] doesn't have an item 1

Comment: You're not iterating over an array. You're iterating over object keys. `m` is an object, with one key named "0".  `m[0]` is key 0 of object m, which contains [1].

Comment: @DanielBeck *youre not iterating over an array* , yes he is. he iterates over m[0]

Comment: ugh, you're right.  I brainfarted. Mea culpa.

Comment: @DanielBeck *to err is human* ;)

Comment: This is because the `c` in `for(var c in m[0]) document.write(c);` is they key/index of the arrray and u r misinterpreting it to be the value at that index.

Comment: Yes, that's because I am used to the way `for...in` works in python. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var c of m[0]) document.write(c);
```

The for..in operator passes keys ( the only key in your array is 0 ), the for..of operator passes values ( but its quite new [ES6])

Alternatively, get the data at c´s position:

```
for(var c in m[0]) document.write(m[0][c]);
```

Or even more elegant:

```
m[0].forEach(document.write);
```

Note that your structure is like the following:

```
var m = {0:[1]}
//is actually:
var m = {
   0:{
     0:1,
     prototype:Array.prototype
    }
};
```

Comment: I see. I am used to the `for ... in` of python which is different

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate over all keys of `m` then:

```
for(var c in m) document.write(m[c]);
```

If you need to pick only `0` key of `m` then:

```
for(var c in m[0]) document.write(m[0][c]);
```

Answer (score 1):

U are printing c, I think you want to print m[x]

```js
function run() {
  var m = {0:[1]}
  document.write(JSON.stringify(m[0]) + "<br>");
  for(var c in m[0]) document.write(m[c]);   
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: this works because of the lucky key naming... *c in m[0]* + *m[c]* will fail in many cases...